# Python Tkinter - unsure how to use messagebox.askretrycancel() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function I am working on that displays different figures based on the keyword inputted and decided to use simpledialog.askstring() to display a messagebox that I can input my keyword into. When I enter the keyword wrong, I want to display a messagebox that asks me if I want to retry and reenter the keyword but I can't seem to get this to work for me.

My code so far:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import simpledialog, messagebox

def display_figure():
    application_window = Tk()
    application_window.withdraw()

    answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "What figure do you want to look at: 'Fig1', 'Fig2', 'Fig3', or 'Fig4'?", parent=application_window)
    if   answer == 'Fig1': (Code to display Fig1)
    elif answer == 'Fig2': (Code to display Fig2)
    elif answer == 'Fig3': (Code to display Fig3)
    elif answer == 'Fig4': (Code to display Fig4)
    else: messagebox.askretrycancel("Question", "Error: Not a recognized keyword. Do you want to try again?")
```

I'm not sure how to loop back to the previous question to ask for a keyword again when the "Retry" button in the messagebox produced is clicked on so any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`askretrycancel` always return Boolean value. When pressed Retry returns `True` and `False` when pressed cancel. You will need to use `while` loop and don't break it till the answer is correct or the `Cancel` is pressed. Here is code:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import simpledialog, messagebox

def display_figure():
    application_window = Tk()
    application_window.withdraw()
    while True:
        answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "What figure do you want to look at: 'Fig1', 'Fig2', 'Fig3', or 'Fig4'?", parent=application_window)
        if   answer == 'Fig1': print(answer);break
        elif answer == 'Fig2': print(answer);break
        elif answer == 'Fig3': print(answer);break
        elif answer == 'Fig4': print(answer);break
        else:
            if messagebox.askretrycancel("Question", "Error: Not a recognized keyword. Do you want to try again?") == False:
                break


display_figure()
```